# issues with showing loading image on form submission using functional react hook in rectjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below works fine and can successfully show and hide a loading image as data is being fetched from database.

```
const App = () => {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


const base = useBase();
const tab1 = base.getTableByNameIfExists('myfirst_table');
 // grab all the records from that table
 const records = useRecords(tab1);


useEffect(() => {
  if (records){
    setLoading(false)
  }
}, [records]);



}

// return content goes here
```

**Here is my issue:**  in the code below, Am trying to post a message when button is click.
In this regard, I want to show and hide loading images as form is being submitted but it keeps displaying error "**Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."**. This is case of form submission

**here is a sample code**

```
const Post = () => {

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

 function handleChange(event) {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

// set loading to true on button click
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
/*
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
}, []);
*/

// send message to 
const message = "Hello Friends";


// set loading to false to hide the image after form submission


useEffect(() => {

// post data
  if (message){
    setLoading(false)
  }
}, [message]);



}
```

// return content goes here

Comment: `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);` is defined two times in `Post` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks should only be called from the top level of a functional component, i.e. outside any nested functions, loops, if statements etc.

You have following statement

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

inside `handleSubmit` function and it is also duplicate as same statement is already present at the start of `Post` component's body.

From the official docs: [Rules of Hooks - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
>   Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By
>   following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same
>   order each time a component renders

Answer (score 0):

you are using same state multiple time and your are using both `useState` and `useEffect`
inside a function, react hooks can only be used inside react functional components.